# issue with running poisson model

Tags: r, lme4, poisson

I am trying to run a Poisson model in R. I checked a number of web sites to do this and I believe the code below should work. However, I am getting an error message that indicates that there is an unused argument. I don't understand what the issue is.

```
library(lme4)
m1<-lmer(sum ~ Lunch + intervention_y_n + (1 | prcid), 
         data=data_long_1, family = "poisson"(link = "log"))
```

> Error in lmer(sum ~ Lunch + intervention_y_n + (1 | prcid), data = data_long_1,  :
> unused argument (family = poisson(link = "log"))

Comment: You need `glmer()` for GLMM's.  `lmer()` is for LMM's (assuming gaussian errors).

Comment: @aosmith, took the liberty of expanding on your comment.  If you'd like to post an answer I can delete mine ...

Comment: @BenBolker Your answer looks great (plus you know all that detail about when the change happened :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `glmer()` for generalized linear mixed models (e.g. a Poisson model). `lmer()` is for linear mixed models only (Gaussian response with an identity link), so it doesn't have a `family` argument.

This code worked until fairly recently (4 months ago). If you check the [NEWS file for lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/news.html) you'll see that  version 1.1-22, which was released in April 2020, disabled the automatic forwarding of `lmer(..., family=...)` to `glmer`. However, this usage had been deprecated (i.e., gave a warning message telling you not to use it) starting in 2013 ...